# undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.map(function(t){return u(t)})')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

"undefined is not a function" is probably a widely asked question. But I could not find a solution to the exact problem I have here.

My code is as follows:

How I call function where problem arise:

```
...
service.queryListToInfoList(response.data || []);
...
```

In service,

```
export const queryListToInfoList = queryList => queryList.map(ql => queryToInfo(ql));

export const queryToInfo = query => { //some process; return {..}};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "16.5.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1"
    ...
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.0"
    ...
 }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

In the end I get some error logs from some different devices saying :

> "undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.map(function(t){return u(t)})')" indicating "queryListToInfoList" function. But generally it works.

`queryList` is always an array. (response.data)

What might be causing the problem here?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Digging a bit more, I realize all those error logs have something in common. This crash happens after an Android intent e.g: POWER_DISCONNECTED, RINGER_MODE_CHANGED, CONFIGURATION_CHANGED.

Comment: Try to console.log it before calling t.map

Comment: sounds like `queryToInfo` is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found the problem. It happens because sometimes apisauce/axios cannot parse response.data correctly. So instead of object it passes string and the rest throws error when referencing string.map()

Here is the issue [axios parse error](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1723)

As a workaround, I added type checks before setting response.data, so it is now like following after api calls:

```
if(response.ok && typeof response.data === 'object'){
  dispatch(setData(response.data || []));
}
```

Beware this should be okay only if expected data is actually object type.

Answer (score 0):

this might sound silly, did you tried importing the queryListToInfoList as 
`import {queryListToInfoList} from './path_to service'` or `import queryListToInfoList from './path_to service'`. i have seen these error happen usually when imported in a wrong way